# I really need help putting in another variable (Java) For handling the bottom 3 cases:

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CandleLine
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  double dollars, answer;
  int shipmentCode;

  dollars = getPrice();
  shipmentCode = getCode();
  answer = getTotalPrice(dollars,shipmentCode);
  output(answer,dollars);
  finish();
  }

 public static double getPrice()
 {
  double price = 0.0;
  boolean done = false;

  while (!done)
  {
   String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the original price\n(do not use commas or dollar signs)\n or click Cancel to exit:");

   if (answer == null) finish();

   try
   {
    price = Double.parseDouble(answer);
    if (price <= 0) throw new NumberFormatException();
    else done = true;
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException e)
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your entry was not in the proper format.","Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
  }
  return price;
 }

 public static int getCode()
 {
  int code = 0;
  boolean done = false;

  while (!done)
  {
   try
   {
    String message = "Enter the shipment code:" + "\n\n1) Priority\n2) Express\n3) Standard\n\n";

    code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,message));

    if (code<1 || code>3) throw new NumberFormatException();
    else done = true;
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException e)
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a 1, 2, or 3.","Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
  }
  return code;
 }

 public static double getTotalPrice(double price, int shipmentcode)
 {
  double totalprice = 0.0;

  switch(shipmentcode)
  {
   case 1:
    totalprice = 14.95 + price;
    break;
   case 2:
    totalprice = 11.95 + price;
    break;
   case 3:
    totalprice = 5.95 + price;
    break;
  }
  return totalprice;
 }

 public static void output(double totalprice, double price)
 {
  DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("$#.00");

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your shipment fee is" + shipmentcode,"Shipment Fee",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your total cost is" + twoDigits.format(totalprice),"Price Total",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
 }
 public static void finish()
 {
  System.exit(0);
 }
}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
The case 3 needs to be zero when it total price exceeds $75 (no shipping cost over that price). How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 case 3:
    if (price > 75 ) {
      totalPrice = price;
    } else {
      totalprice = 5.95 + price;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you. I do need help with one more thing - how do I make the shipment code apply to all three cases (i.e. "Your shipment cost is [1,2,3]"

Comment: Anything outside of the switch() would apply to all 3 cases, no?

Comment: Take your best guess in an edit to your post, and we can correct you. Doing what you are told will not make you a programmer, but a mindless robot. Take a guess, and then we can correct you so that you learn.

Comment: But I now get a different error. No matter what I input, the output value is always 5.95 for the shipping, even with an if...else statement.

Answer (score 0):

So in total, how many possibilities are there for the shipping cost of an order?

Comment: 2 regular ones, then one with 2 possibilities, so 4 in total. How do I make it so that "Your shipment fee is [case 1, case 2, case 3]" so that it only chooses one? Is it something related to DecimalFormat?

Comment: Right, there are 4 possibilities. What variables does the decision depend on? Can you sketch a table of all possible cases?

Answer (score 0):

```
final double [] shipmentprice = {14.95, 11.95, 5.95};
public static double getTotalPrice (final double price, final int shipmentcode)
{
    return price + shipmentprice[shipmentcode -1];
}
```

A shorter code, but not very object oriented. I'm not sure whether I see an Enum rising. :)